# Looking to optimize multiple melee attacks

Tags: dnd-4e, optimization, fighter, melee-combat

I'm trying to find 2 classes to hybrid into that maximize the attack-shift-attack-shift-attack style powers. I already have the fighter powers of Tempest Dance and Storm of Blows, but what other class has powers like this? I've looked through warlord and there's nothing really there. I've looked through Paladin and Ranger and I didn't see much past 2 attacks, a primary and a secondary.

One caveat is that I'm a polearm fighter, so no dual weapon builds.

Comment: _Why_ do you want to do this? Multi-targeting is generally much weaker than focused fire.

Answer (score 3):

### Barbarian's a good bet.

Vault the Fallen (encounter 1), Shoulder Slam (encounter 17), and Rampaging Dragon Strike (encounter 27) are all in the core PHB2 that introduced them. Can't find a lot that's directly useful to you in Primal Power since that's when they introduced the two-weapon builds for barbarians. Rages tend not to be initial multiattacks in this fashion, but many of them have riders that do additional things on hit, which will help the multiattacks you do have.

As always, if you've got Compendium access, you can effectively look through the entire Dragon Magazine backlog for other Barbarian powers that might be relevant to your interests.

Comment: Thanks! I found the item Staff of the Traveler and mocked up a crazy teleporting monk/warlock hybrid from it, and my GM said he would let me try and "create" a glaive (since I'm a polearm fighter) with the ability if I find blink dog blood and other stuff, so pairing that item with the Eladrin items, and a couple feats, the attack-shift 1-attack becomes attack-teleport 7-attack which gives me tons of tactical positioning and movement around battlefiend. There's a feat called Staff of Travelers that lets you shift 1 when casting divine powers, but that specifically says you have to use a staff.

Comment: For closure, I wanted to add that you gave me a great idea to search the DDI Compendium. I searched for powers with "third" in them, and ended up replacing the hybrid powers I was forced to pick because you have to alternate between your hybrid classes, with fighter powers from lower levels. I grabbed Storm of Blows as a lvl13 encounter power, and Serpentine Dance as a lvl15 daily power. That gives me those 2, and my Tempest Dance (lvl1 daily power). Along with some other things like Silverstep and Etherial Step as utility powers, he's gonna be fun to play.

Comment: An update to this, my character has hit epic, and I found an epic feat called Feywild Warrior that lets me teleport me and a creature I hit with a martial daily attack power 5 squares, so my guy essentially teleports in, attacks, teleports to the next guy and repeats the attack, then a third time, and teleports all the enemies I hit into a clump for the AE burster in the group. :)